# "Catchall" TLD or single-word Hostnames

Tags: bind, nameserver, tld

I have the TLD zone .lcl set-up and everything works fine, except that the config:

```
$TTL    3600
@       IN      SOA     lcl. root.lcl. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      nameserver.

*                       A       192.168.1.3
```

does not allow me to resolve "lcl" itself.

While being somewhat obvious, that actually is what im trying to achieve, single-word-domains should be resolved using a Bind9 daemon. Is that possible at all?

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll run into issues with the OS automatically adding it's local 'search suffix' to dot-less names. My first observation though is that you don't appear to have a record in that zone file for 'lcl'. I'm pretty sure the * entry only covers '*.lcl', not 'lcl' itself. You need another A record with 'lcl.' or '@' on the left hand side (Assuming you're testing by doing a lookup for 'lcl' that isn't an NS query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this but try

```
@               A            192.168.1.3
```

Looks like the wildcard requires something